# Extract value from xml with robot framework

Tags: xml, robotframework

This is my XML code:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schema.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body> 
<ns4:DebitUsageTransactionResponse xmlns:ns4="http://soa.med.com/PDK/v1"
xmlns:ns3="http://exceptions.soa.med.com/PDK/v1"
xmlns:ns2="http://extensions.soa.med.com/PDK/v1"><DebitTransactionResp>
<TransactionID>8682220199021025</TransactionID></DebitTransactionResp>
</ns4:DebitUsageTransactionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I need to extract the "TransactionID" value with robot framework.  How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you looked into the XML Library? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: Yes i have looked the XML Library....

Comment: @Dali are you sure you have had a proper look at it? Because quickly looking through it, your question seems pretty mundane for SO :(

Comment: @Dali: if you looked at the XML library, share what you learned. Was there nothing that would work for you? Did you actually try to use it? Edit your question to include that information -- what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: After parsing my xml I tried to get the value but I have problem caused by my complex code. I have tried with simple code xml and it's done but with this example I faced an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
${text}=    Get Element Text  ${path_to_xml}    xpath_to_tag
Log To Console    ${text}
```

${path_to_xml} can be a path to an XML file, a string containing XML, or an already parsed XML element

For reference:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Elements

Comment: Hi @Krishna Barri , can you check this one once
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165203/getting-error-while-parsing-the-xml-content-in-the-json-key-element-in-robot-tes?noredirect=1#comment120475023_68165203

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to extract all the xml object information and organize it in the form of a dictionary of key:value pairs. Here's one way to do it:

```
${xml}=    Parse Xml    file_path
@{header}=    Get Elements    ${xml}    ${header_xml_object_xpath}
${elemList}=    Get Elements    ${header}[0]    *
@{elemList}=    Convert to List    ${elemList}
&{xmlDict}=    Create Dictionary
: FOR    ${item}    IN    @{elemList}
\    Set to Dictionary    ${xmlDict}    ${item.tag}=${item.text}
```

In this example: 
${item.tag} gives the element tag e.g. In  the element tag is 'userName'
${item.text} gives the value of the element e.g. In myuser the value of the element is 'myuser'

Converting the xml object to a dictionary provides the flexibility to easily access all the information on the elements in the specific xml object.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
{root}=    Parse XML    ${path_to_xml}

${text}=    Get Element Text    {root}    Body/DebitUsageTransactionResponse/

Log To Console    ${text}
```