# Getting error while parsing the XML content in the JSON key element in ROBOT Test framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I am writing a keyword in the robot Automation framework.
(I am new to this framework & I stuck executing the below)

temp.json file

```
 {
    "Arg": {
           "xmlValue": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><reginfo xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:testing\" version=\"1\" state=\"full\"><reg aid=\"sip:xyz@home1.net\" id=\"abcd7\" state=\"terminated\"><contact id=\"9\" state=\"terminated\" event=\"dre\"><uri>sip:[1234:bbb:ccc:ddd]</uri></contact></registration></reginfo>"
    }
    }
```

Below is my keyword_test.robot file:

loaded_json_path this variable contains the path of the JSON file, LOAD_JSON is the another keyword

```
REGISTER_4G_MSISDN
    ${loaded_json_temp}  LOAD_JSON   ${loaded_json_path}
    ${Request_val}     Stringify Json  ${loaded_json_temp} // I am facing problem in this line
 
LOAD_JSON
    [Arguments] ${file}
    ${json} Load JSON From File ${file}
    ${json_value}=   Stringify Json  ${json}
    log     ${json_value}
    return from keyword ${json_value}
```

Error is this which I am getting in the log file:

[image]

if the image is not clear , this is the error which I am getting

Evaluating expression 'json.loads('''{"length": 12, "value": "<reginfo xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:testing" version="1" state="full"><reg aid="sip:xyz@home1.net" id="abcd7" state="terminated"><contact id="9" state="terminated" event="dre">sip:[1234:bbb:ccc:ddd]"}''')' failed: ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 41 (char 40)

Comment: you are mixing json and xml. `json.loads` is expecting to get a json string as input. But the input string you pass to it is xml string

Comment: okay, Any idea on how I can load the XML string and how to process it?

Comment: I am not familiar with robotframework.

Comment: use xml library: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html